# How do you check the equivalence of a numpy.int64 value stored in a tf.Tensor dataset object in Python 3?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.x, int32

I would like to know whether there is an easy way to check the equivalence of an int32 value stored in a tf.Tensor dataset object of class 'numpy.int64'.  The integer value will change over time, and I would like to get a logical indicator of 'True' when the value is 2, and 'False' when it is not.  I am working with Python 3 and TensorFlow 2.5.0.

Here are some specifics.  When I call:

```
print(class(token))
```

on my dataset object (named 'token'), I see:

```
tf.Tensor([[2]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=int32)
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

I would like to check whether the integer value stored in 'token' equals 2, and receive a logical indicator 'True' or 'False' as the value changes relative to the reference value of 2.  It seems like this should be easy, but no matter what sort of indexing or function call I try, I cannot seem to access the integer stored in 'token'.  How can I do this?

When I call:

```
print(token)
```

I see:

```
0
```

When I try:

```
print(tf.math.equal(token,[[2]]))
```

I see:

```
tf.Tensor([[False]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=bool)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Correction:  The title should read:  "How do you check the equivalence of an int32 value stored in a tf.Tensor dataset object (class 'numpy.int64') in Python 3?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this

```
tf.squeeze(tf.math.equal(token,[[2]])).numpy()
```

This should output `True`.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you, Anurag!  Could you kindly add how I could additionally access the integer contained in this data object (rather than just checking the number's equivalence), and do some calculations with it?  What do I need to do to extract the number itself?

Comment: To answer my own (last) question, it appears you can simply call float on the tf.Float object to recover the integer for normal calculations:  These two calls yield 0.6666 and 'float', respectively:   print(float(tf.squeeze(token.numpy()))/3), 
type(float(tf.squeeze(token.numpy()))/3)

Comment: Thankyou and welcome buddy! To access the value you can do this : `np.squeeze(token.numpy()).item()` here I am squeezing the value using numpy instead of TF. Please Upvote if my answer helped 

Comment: Thanks!  I tried to upvote the, but I don't have the points to do so yet!